# Loading OSM data into QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I have been trying to use OSM maps and my data is 60 GB around. I have imported it to QGIS as a vector layer but it seems the data is so big that the rendering is taking forever.

My system has Intel Dual Core and 2GB of RAM. So can anyone please tell me how i can work with my data without any rendering problems.

please help me work around this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested above you could load the data into a PostGIS database, or a Spatialite database. If you are a newcomer to QGIS you might find Spatialite simpler to use.

In either case do not try to load your data into QGIS without first setting sensible extents (a small area) or QGIS will try to load all 60 GBs of the data and the system will collapse.

N.

Comment: alright, so can you tell me where to set the extent for rendering.
also what i need to setup a spatialite or PostGIS database?

Comment: What I would do is draw a polygon in Google Earth, a rectangle say, with extents of say 20 km x 20 km. Save this a KML file (not KMZ) and load it into QGIS. This will set some reasonable extents. Then try loading your OSM data (don't bother about databases at this stage).

Answer (score 5):

You have to put the data into a POSTGIS database.

QGIS tries to load all data into memory, and 60GB of data is far to much for 2GB RAM.