# Uploading large OSM files to PostGIS with command line

Tags: qgis, postgis, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql, quickosm

I'm trying to upload the nationwide US OSM dataset from Geofabrik website to a PostGIS database (about 200 GB).

For small OSM files, I'm able to import the OSM file as layers into QGIS with the QuickOSM plugin and then send the layer I need to PostGIS from there.

However, as mentioned in this post: [Loading OSM data into QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88073/loading-osm-data-into-qgis)
loading in very large OSM files won't work since QGIS will try to load everything into memory.  I tried imported my 200 GB OSM file and it keeps crashing midway.

I have decided to use the command line to import directly POSTGIS using OSM2PGSQL.  I would hopefully like the generated tables with OSM2PGSQL to be of the same format as the ones QGIS generates (one table for linestrings, one table for multipolygons, one table for points, etc).

I found this tutorial, but I don't know how to write the configuration file mentioned here, what paths to use, etc.
https://osm2pgsql.org/examples/road-length/

Can you explain the fastest basic way to get the OSM file into PostGIS?

I don't need to add any custom parameters or specification in the config file. I would just like to get the data into the PostGIS database as soon as I can so I can start running spatial queries.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Please [Edit] this to focus on one specific issue.

Comment: Since you are using qgis why don't you use the database manager or the geocat plugin? So much easier.

Comment: so the database manager would bypass loading the OSM file into QGIS and put it straight into POSTGIS without overloading memory?

Comment: i tried using database manager to upload the OSM file, but it only uploaded the point geometries not the lines which i need.  do you know how i could make it import lines?

Comment: @GforGIS i checked https://www.geocat.net/docs/bridge/qgis/latest/, and i don't see any mentioned of being able to upload to POSTGIS without first uploading a vector layer?

Comment: @VivekReddy I suggest you use the QuickOSM plugin to download the layers that you want from OSM in QGIS then check the layers on QGIS then upload them using the Database Manager or GeoCAT. You can have better control over what you want to upload or you can upload everything in one go. Now if you want to directly upload OSM formats data to PostGIS and you are open to other technologies, give a try to "FME Form".